# Can I create string enum?

Tags: rust, enums

I am wondering is it possible to create `enum` with constant string values in Rust?

I found this previous question: [How do I get an enum as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710187/how-do-i-get-an-enum-as-a-string) which shows a work around that I can use to stringify variants of an `enum` (I can use `.to_string()` on `enum` variants and get their name as a string).

That question was helpful, but this is what I want to achieve:

```rust
enum StringEnum {
    Hello = "Hello",
    World = "World"
}
```

Comment: Enum derives from *enumerate*, so it will always want an `isize` for each entry.

Comment: @C14L so it is impossible because strings can have different sizes and every `enum`  value must be the same size. Am I right ?

Comment: Correct. In the answer you linked to, a Crate is mentioned that seems to do what you are looking for: [strum_macros](https://crates.io/crates/strum_macros)

Comment: The discriminator of an enum is always an integral type in Rust. Implementing a function returning the string value as an `&'static str` or implementing the `Display` trait like in the linked quest is the way to go. You could use macros to make reduce the boilerplate.

Comment: @C14L Yes I saw this dependency, but I am just learning Rust, so I didn't want to use dependencies. Anyway thank you for your answer. If you want to add an answer with explanation, I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

If you have an enum like this:

```rust
enum HelloWorld {
    Hello,
    World
}
```

`Hello` and `World` are enum *variants*. Every variant of an enum is assigned to a single integer value. This is known as the [discriminant](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html). Currently, discriminants are only allowed to be integers, not arbitrary types like `&'static str`, although that may change in the future.

If you want to be able to convert your enum to a string, you can write a method that does this manually:

```rust
impl HelloWorld {
    fn as_str(&self) -> &'static str {
        match self {
            HelloWorld::Hello => "Hello",
            HelloWorld::World => "World"
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can have this done for you with the [`strum_macros`](https://crates.io/crates/strum_macros) crate:

```rust
#[derive(strum_macros::Display)]
pub enum StringEnum {
    Hello,
    World
}


fn main() {
    let hello: &'static str = StringEnum::Hello.into(); // "Hello"
    let world: String = StringEnum::World.to_string(); // "World"
}
```

There are a couple other methods mentioned in [How do I get an enum as a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710187/how-do-i-get-an-enum-as-a-string)