# How can I display an enum in lowercase?

Tags: rust, enums, io

I have an enum:

```
pub enum BoxColour {
    Red,
    Blue,
}
```

I not only want to [get this value as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710187/how-do-i-get-an-enum-as-a-string), but I want the value to be converted to lower case.

This works:

```
impl Display for BoxColour {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        fmt.write_str(match self {
            BoxColour::Red => "red",
            BoxColour::Blue => "blue",
        })?;
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

When the list of colours grows, this list would need to be updated.

If I use the `write!` macro, it does not seem possible to manipulate the result because `write!` returns an instance of `()` instead of a `String`:

```
impl Display for BoxColour {
    fn fmt(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(formatter, "{:?}", self)
    }
}
```

This suggests that this is working through side effects and maybe we could hack the same place in memory the value is going, but even if that is possible, it probably isn't a good idea...

Comment: *`write!` returns an instance of `()`* — it does not. It returns a `fmt::Result`, as shown by the _return type of `fmt`_.

Comment: ...and `fmt::Result` is a `type` for `Result<(), fmt::Error>`.

Comment: You have already answered the question you have **asked** ("How can I Display an enum in lowercase?"). Please clarify exactly what it is you are asking beyond that.

Comment: The question [you've linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32710187/how-do-i-get-an-enum-as-a-string) has an answer using strum, and [strum allows you to customize what the `Display` format will be](https://docs.rs/strum_macros/0.21.1/strum_macros/derive.Display.html). It seems like you've linked to a suitable solution.

Comment: @Shepmaster, thanks for the response.  @Smitop correctly understood my intention (below).  Yes, I meant to indicate the success path for `Result` is `()` instead of `String` or something I might know how to work with.  I saw `strum`, but couldn't get that to work either, but that's a question for a different day.

Comment: why the first solution is a problem for you that how you should do it.

Comment: @Stargateur, The first solution is a problem because the only thing I want to change is the case.  This solution is duplicating information, is prone to human error, and won't scale nicely (imagine if there were hundreds of values in this list instead of just two).

Comment: rust will warn you, that why rust is nice, your code will literally not compile

Comment: @Stargateur, Rust can't warn you about everything.  For example, it would not care if I provided the value of `Red` as "ref" or "green" or "fdsf342sef".

Comment: @BrianKessler have test :p but typo error are hard to see, you could do a typo IN the enum variant don't see it until someone tell you, same problem same result

Comment: @Stargateur, I think you are missing the point.  I just wanted a concise way to automate converting enums to strings without needing to explicitly code each result and then maintain both the enums and the conversion process.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [`strum`](https://docs.rs/strum/) crate provides a derive macro for implementing `Display` for an enum, and optionally lowercasing the variant names:

```rust
use strum_macros::Display;

#[derive(Display)]
// If we don't care about inner capitals, we don't need to set `serialize_all` 
// and can leave parenthesis empty.
#[strum(serialize_all = "snake_case")]
pub enum BoxColour {
    Red,
    Blue,
    LightGreen,  // example of how inner capitals are treated
}

fn main() {
    for c in [BoxColour::Red, BoxColor::Blue, BoxColor::LightGreen] {
        println!("{}", c);
    }
}
```

You will also need the corresponding dependency on `strum` in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
strum = { version = "0.21", features = ["derive"] }
```

This should print:

```
red
blue
light_green
```

`strum` will generate code similar to the `match` with `BoxColour::Red => "red",` cases that you mentioned, but without the need to update it manually.

Comment: Kevin Reid,  Cheers for response.  It didn't work "as-is", but I've fixed it.  :-)  Some might quibble about adding the dependency, but admittedly this is a bit more elegant than @Smitop's solution.  I'm not sure whether Stackoverflow allows me to change the accepted answer, but I'll try.  :-)

Comment: @BrianKessler you can change anytime you like accepted answer is just "that what I choice to fix my problem" hint for future reader, don't worry about that.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way to do that without needing to manually update `Display::fmt` every time you add a new colour by using the derived `Debug` implementation and lowercasing that:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum BoxColour {
    Red,
    Blue,
}

impl fmt::Display for BoxColour {
    fn fmt(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(formatter, "{}", format!("{:?}", self).to_lowercase())
    }
}
```

[(playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=12e634dd9a7a5f51aabcf238007593d0)

Note that `write!` returns a `Result<(), fmt::Error>` (which is a `fmt::Result`), *not* a raw `()`.

But consider if it would just be better to manually update the list, or use a macro to specify that. Also consider how colours with multiple words (such as `LightBlue`) should be lowercased: is `lightblue` what you want there?

Comment: you format the argument you send to a formater ? that feel hacky and bad

Comment: @Stargateur the code does seem hacky, but the nested format is the only way to make the Debug output lowercase: there isn't any format specifier for general lowercasing (`LowerHex`/`LowerExp` exists but are only applicable to formatting numbers).

Answer (score 4):

As an extension to @Smitop's answer, it is possible to generally display any value in lowercase by using a custom formatter, as such:

```rust
use std::fmt::{self, Write};

struct LowercaseFormatter<'a, 'b>(pub &'a mut fmt::Formatter<'b>);

impl<'a, 'b> fmt::Write for LowercaseFormatter<'a, 'b> {
    fn write_str(&mut self, s: &str) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
        for ch in s.chars() {
            self.0.write_fmt(format_args!("{}", ch.to_lowercase()))?;
        }
        
        Ok(())
    }
}
```

Then use it as such:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum BoxColour {
    Red,
    Blue,
}

impl fmt::Display for BoxColour {
    fn fmt(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(LowercaseFormatter(formatter), "{:?}", self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", BoxColour::Red); // "red"
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e90f6348c846c6486b5449603f544455)

This version doesn't allocate a string on every formatting, but it is also not very optimized, calling `write_fmt` for every character is relatively costly.

One alternative for just `ascii` characters, is to call `write_char(ch.to_ascii_lowercase())`, but writing a string a character at a time is also relatively costly.

A proper solution would partition the string in some way to be able to write all already lowercase characters all at once, and only special case the uppercase ones.