# How should I assign this enum based on the loops itera/tion/tor?

Tags: rust, enums

```
enum MealTime {
    Breakfast,
    Lunch,
    Dinner,
}

 for n in 1..3 {
        let mealc: MealTime = match n {
            1 => MealTime::Breakfast,
            2 => MealTime::Lunch,
            3 => MealTime::Dinner,
        };
```

At first I tried doing `for meal in MealTime {}` but discovered that would not work because rust does not support iterating through enums (at least not by default or without implementing the trait yourself). So then I decided to just use a standard for loop ranged by an integer only to realize that using the iterator to match a variable to one of the enums types causes an error:

##### error[E0004]: non-exhaustive patterns: `i32::MIN..=0_i32` and `4_i32..=i32::MAX` not covered.

How is this supposed to be done? I would think that matching for all 3 cases of n being 1, 2, and 3 would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Rust doesn't know that `n` will only ever be one of 1, 2, or 3, it assumes that `n` could be any `i32`. So what to do if `n == 5`? If you're sure any value other than 1, 2, or 3 is impossible to occur, you can give the compiler a hint with the [`unreachable!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.unreachable.html) macro, like this:

```rust
for n in 1..=3 {
    let mealc: MealTime = match n {
        1 => MealTime::Breakfast,
        2 => MealTime::Lunch,
        3 => MealTime::Dinner,
        _ => unreachable!(),
    };
}
```

If `n` ever is something other than 1, 2, or 3 this program will panic. By the way, you will have to write `1..=3` instead of `1..3`. `1..3` is the exclusive range, `1..=3` the inclusive [range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html).

Answer (score 4):

A replacement for `for meal in MealTime {}` could be:

```
for meal in [MealTime::Breakfast, MealTime::Lunch, MealTime::Dinner] {
    // do something with meal
}
```

---

For more explanations and solutions, see [Is there a way to iterate through the values of an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371534/in-rust-is-there-a-way-to-iterate-through-the-values-of-an-enum)