# How to generate a vec of enum options in Rust

Tags: rust

Is there a way to do the below by iterating over enum in Rust.

```rust
enum ProductCategory{
    Dairy,
    Daycare,
    BabyCare
}

fn main() {

    let product_categories = vec![ProductCategory::Dairy, ProductCategory::Daycare, ProductCategory::BabyCare];

}
```

This to send over an api what all the possible value a user  can select for a particular field. (`serde serialize will be added`)

Answer (score 1):

A quick example using the [strum crate](https://docs.rs/strum/0.21.0/strum/).

```rust
let product_categories: Vec<_> = ProductCategory::iter().collect();
```

With this crate, you can iterate over the variants of enums, convert them to/from string representation, associate string metadata with variants, etc...

The complete example:

```rust
use strum::{IntoEnumIterator, EnumIter};

#[derive(Debug, EnumIter)]
enum ProductCategory {
    Dairy, Daycare, BabyCare,
}

fn main() {
    let product_categories = ProductCategory::iter().collect::<Vec<_>>();
    println!("{:?}", product_categories);
}
```

output:

```
[Dairy, Daycare, BabyCare]
```

Add to *Cargo.toml*:

```
[dependencies]
strum = { version = "0.21", features = ["derive"] }
```

Comment: how your answer different than https://stackoverflow.com/a/55056427/7076153 ?

Comment: It shows usage of `.collect()` in answer to the specific title of this post, "generate a vec of enum options". The other example just iterates over them @Stargateur