# Iterating over an enum

Tags: rust, enums

So I'm trying to build a simple deck generator using Rust. I'm new to the language so I haven't grasped everything about it yet.

I want to iterate over both a Suits enum and a Values enum, make a Card struct using them, and then push that Card into the Deck's cards vector.

So far I tried making a static enum and iterating over that like this:

```
        static SUITE_ITER: [Cards::Suits; 4] = [
          Cards::Suits::HEARTS,
          Cards::Suits::CLUBS, 
          Cards::Suits::DIAMONDS,
          Cards::Suits::SPADES
        ];
        for suit in SUITE_ITER.into_iter() {...}
```

However, I get this error message that I don't fully understand. Any tips?

cannot move out of static item `SUITE_ITER`
move occurs because `SUITE_ITER` has type `[Suits; 4]`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

Comment: Use `for suit in &SUITE_ITER { … }`

Comment: Add `#[derive(Copy)]` in front of the definition of `enum Suits`.

Answer (score 4):

Enum values cannot be *copied* by default. If you want to make a type "copyable", usually what you can do is annotate it with the `Copy` proc macro via `#[derive(Copy)]`. As an alternative, you might want to use *references* to the values.

Your code uses `into_iter`. I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733811/what-is-the-difference-between-iter-and-into-iter).

You might also take a look at the [strum](https://crates.io/crates/strum) crate and read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371534/in-rust-is-there-a-way-to-iterate-through-the-values-of-an-enum) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over a reference into the `SUITE_ITER` array. Like

```rust
static SUITE_ITER: [Cards::Suits; 4] = [
    Cards::Suits::HEARTS,
    Cards::Suits::CLUBS,
    Cards::Suits::DIAMONDS,
    Cards::Suits::SPADES,
];

for suit in &SUITE_ITER {
    // ...
}
```