# Write a macro to iterate over all values of an enum and create a const

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have an `enum` which I want to use as a `const` in `match` statements as well. I am trying to create a macro like below:

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! enum_consts {
    ($name:ident) => {
        // Use the iter method to get the iterator
        for variant in $name::iter() {
            // Use paste to create identifiers from literals
            paste::paste! {
                // Declare a const for each variant
                const [< $name _ $variant >]: u8 = variant as u8;
            }
        }
    };
}

enum Color {
    Red,
    Green
}

enum_consts!{ Color }
```

However, I am facing issues in iterating over the enum in the macro  with below error:

```
error: macro expansion ignores token `for` and any following
 --> abc.rs:1951:9
     |
1951 |         for variant in $name::iter() {
     |         ^^^
```

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Macros basically paste the generated code at the call site, and a `for` loop is not valid at module level. `Color::iter()` also doesn't exist, unless it's in code you haven't shown us.

Comment: *"I have an `enum` which I want to use as a `const` in `match` statements as well."* - `enum` values [can already be used in `match` statements](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d7339baf34e6598ccf380726499e8aca). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In fact, I didn't even know that you **could** match against `const`s. It must be a new thing.

Comment: [Relavent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371534/in-rust-is-there-a-way-to-iterate-through-the-values-of-an-enum)

Answer (score 2):

I'd argue that this is an XY Problem, because enum entries are already kind of `const`s.

In your example, the values `Color::Red` and `Color::Green` are the two values that can be used in const contexts; hence I would argue that they already are const-like. I don't see any advantage of having them declared separately again as `const` values.

> I have an `enum` which I want to use as a `const` in `match` statements as well.

Using those values in `match` statements is already possible. In fact it's the intended way:

```rust
pub enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
}

fn main() {
    let color = Color::Red;

    match color {
        Color::Red => println!("Red!"),
        Color::Green => println!("Green!"),
    }
}
```

```
Red!
```

---

If you absolutely dislike the `Color::` in front of the values, you can do `use Color::*` somewhere; although this is commonly seen as an antipattern because it increases the likeliness of name collisions.

But you could for example do this:

```rust
pub enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
}

use Color::*;

fn main() {
    let color = Red;

    match color {
        Red => println!("Red!"),
        Green => println!("Green!"),
    }
}
```

```
Red!
```

If this is done (in actual code bases I know), then it is usually done so only in local scopes:

```rust
pub enum Color {
    Red,
    Green,
}

fn main() {
    use Color::*;

    let color = Red;

    match color {
        Red => println!("Red!"),
        Green => println!("Green!"),
    }
}
```

```
Red!
```

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not really sure what you are trying to solve, you can create a constant from each enum variant like this:

```rs
use paste::paste;

macro_rules! color_consts{
    {
        $(#[$($attr:tt)*])*
        $vis:vis enum $name:ident {
            $($variant:ident,)* 
        }
    } => {
        $(#[$($attr)*])*
        $vis enum $name { $($variant,)* }
        
        $(paste!{const [<$name _ $variant>]:$name = $name::$variant; } )*
    }
}

color_consts! {
    enum Color {
        Red,
        Green,
        Blue,
    }
}
```

This will generate:

```
enum Color { Red, Green, Blue, }
const Color_Red: Color = Color::Red;
const Color_Green: Color = Color::Green;
const Color_Blue: Color = Color::Blue;
```

Though I'm not sure what potential use this would be.